# Verify my proof of $\lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)+g(x)]= L+M$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I am supposed to prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)+g(x)]= L+M$.

Starting to realize I don't really understand the formal definition of a limit, although I do understand the general concept. Anyhow, so far I have:

Given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists R_f,R_g$ s.t. $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$ $\forall x>R_f$ and $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon/2$  $\forall x>R_g$

Choose $R>\max\{R_f,R_g\}$. (Do we want max, min, neither?)

Suppose $x>R$. Then $x>R_f$ and $x>R_g$ whenever $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$ and $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon/2$.

Then $\left\vert\big(f(x)+g(x)\big)-(L+M)\right\vert$ = $\left\vert\big(f(x)-L\big)+\big(g(x)-M\big)\right\vert$ $\le$ $|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-M|$

This implies $|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-M|$ < $\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$ < $\epsilon$ QED.

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof almoast good.

You need $\max$ and not $\min$. Suppose $R_f<R_g$ and you said $R>\min\{R_f,R_g\}$. Then you could have $R<R_g$. Then $x>R\not\Rightarrow \vert g(x)-M\vert<\varepsilon$.

Also, in your third line you need to change "whenever"($\Leftarrow$) to "therefore"($\Rightarrow$).