# Prove that $\pi\in\operatorname{ran}(f)$ where $f(x)=x^3+\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-writing

> Prove that $\pi\in\operatorname{ran}(f)$ where $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $$f(x)=x^3+\sin x.$$

My attempt:

Let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$
$$g(x):=x^3\implies \operatorname{ran}(g)=\Bbb R,\;g(x)\;\text{is bijective, unbounded & continuous on}\;\Bbb R$$
Let $h:\Bbb R\to [-1,1]$
$$h(x):=\sin x\implies\;h(x)\;\text{is periodic, bounded & continuous on}\;\Bbb R$$
Now:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$
so $f(x)$ is bijective, and unbounded as proven for a general case in this post:

[Verify my proof of $\lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)+g(x)]= L+M$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682119/verify-my-proof-of-lim-x-to-infty-fxgx-lm)

$$\implies\exists! x\in\Bbb R\;s.t.\;f(x)=\pi$$

I'm not sure if my argument is precise enough. May I ask for correction & advice on improving my statements? Thank you in advance!

---

Edited:

Injectivity of $f(x)$ without derivative:

$f(x)=x^3+\sin(x)$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$. We can prove $f$ is strictly increasing on every open interval $(a,b)$ where $0<b-a<\pi$.
Since $f$ is odd, let's consider the restriction $f_{|\space[0,+\infty)}$.

First, $\sin(x)$ is strictly increasing on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$. Let's look at all $x>\frac\pi2$ and let's assume it is true that

$f(x+\delta)>f(x)\quad\forall\delta\in(0,\pi),$ that is $$\begin{aligned}(x+\delta)^3+\sin(x+\delta)&>x^3+\sin(x)\\\iff(x+\delta)^3+\sin(x+\delta)-x^3-\sin(x)&>0\\\iff \delta((x+\delta)^2+(x+\delta)x+x^2)+\sin(x+\delta)-\sin(x)&>0\\\iff\delta(x^2+2\delta x+\delta^2+x^2+\delta x+x^2)+2\sin\left(\frac\delta2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+2\delta}2\right)&>0\\\iff\delta(3x^2+3\delta x+\delta^2)+2\sin\left(\frac\delta2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+2\delta}2\right)&>0\end{aligned}$$

Now, from $|\sin(\alpha)|\le|\alpha|,\space|\alpha|\le\frac\pi2$ and $0<\delta<\pi\implies0<\frac{\delta}2<\frac\pi2,$ we have that

$$\left|\sin\left(\frac\delta2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+2\delta}2\right)\right|<\frac{\delta}2\implies 2\sin\left(\frac\delta2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+2\delta}2\right)>2\cdot\frac{-\delta}2=-\delta.$$

Since $x>\frac\pi2>1$, it follows that $3x^2>3$ and in turn, in particular, $\delta(3x^2+3\delta x+\delta^2)>3\delta$ and $\delta(3x^2+3\delta x+\delta^2)+2\sin\left(\frac\delta2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+2\delta}2\right)>3\delta-\delta=2\delta>0$ indeed.

---

Extra edit:
literature: prof. dr. Kurepa S.: Math Analysis, One variable functions, page 34:

> theorem 5, assumptions: \begin{aligned} (1)&\quad I\subseteq\Bbb
>  R\quad\text{is an open interval}\\(2)&\quad f:I\to\Bbb R\ \text{is a
>  monotonous function}\\(3)&\quad I'=f(I)\ \text{is an open interval-finite
>  or infinite}\end{aligned} i.e. If a monotonous function $f$ maps an open
> interval $I$ to an open interval $I'=f(I)$, then $f$ is continuous on
> $I$.

---

Addendum:

Special thanks to @CameronWilliams for mentioning $f(0)=0^3+\sin(0)=0$ and $f(\pi)=\pi^3+\sin(\pi)=\pi^3$, which cleares the path for the IVT.

Comment: While $f$ is indeed bijective, I fail to see how your proof shows that it is injective.  As far as I see, only surjectivity has been proven.  But then the problem only requires surjectivity.

Comment: But if you want to show injectivity, you can show that $f$ is strictly increasing via proving that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.  This is true because \begin{align}f'(x)&=3x^2+\cos x=3x^2+1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\\&\geq 3x^2+1-2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2=\frac52x^2+1\ge 1>0.\end{align}

Comment: @WETutorialSchool, thank you, but we haven't formally gone through derivatives at the university yet, although we had in high-school. I added my attempt to prove the injectivity without derivative.

Comment: Your injectivity proof is incomplete.  You only showed that $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$ if $x_1-x_2$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  You have to show that it is true for any pair $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: what is $\mathcal R_f$

Comment: I don't know why you split the expression into two terms. Just note that $f(x) $ is continuous on $\mathbb {R} $ and tends to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty $. By intermediate value theorem $\mathcal{R} _f=\mathbb{R} $.

Comment: @Masacroso, $\mathcal R_f$ denotes the range/image of a function.

Comment: I have also read the book written by Kurepa.

Comment: @Ante,  glad to hear, it is helpful indeed. (:

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya you can find me in this chatroom if you need to:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96072/hilberts-hotel

Comment: I swapped the really confusing $\mathcal{R}_f$ notation for the accepted standard of $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ instead.

Comment: If you don't want to work with the extended IVT that includes divergence to $\pm \infty$, you could simply argue that $0\in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ and so is $\pi^3$. Since $f$ is continuous, IVT tells you that every value between $0$ and $\pi^3$ is attained and that includes $\pi$. Thus some $x \in (0, \pi)$ exists such that $f(x) = \pi$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, thank you, that will do the job! I see, I just mentioned $x_2=x_1+2k\pi, k\in\Bbb Z$ and totally forgot aboud the suplementary angles.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, may I ask if you could make your comment an answer so that the question isn't in the unanswered questions que?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can argue it by the intermediate value theorem (IVT). $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\pi) = \pi^3$. Assuming you know that $\pi > 1$ and there is no need to prove the continuity of $f$ (not difficult), the intermediate value theorem tells you that there exists an $x\in (0, \pi)$ such that $f(x) = \pi$ since $\pi \in (0,\pi^3)$.